# How to use print command in comprehensions in python?

Tags: python, printing, zip, list-comprehension

I have 2 lists

```
Set = [1,2,3,4,5]
Value = [11,12,14,15,16]
```

I need to print:

```
"Set1 Value=11
 Set2 Value=12
 Set3 Value=14
 .... "
```

My code:

```
k = [print("Set" + str(a)+ " " + "Value=" + str(b) + /n) for i in a,b in zip(Set, Value)]
```

However, I get an erorr saying "Invalid Syntax" in your program. Do comprehensions not accept print? How can I rectify this?

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels

Comment: In python2 `print` is a statement, and statements cannot be mixed with expressions. If you want to do that the only way is to use `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of the file and make `print` a function. In any case that `k` list will just be a list of `None`s, so I don't really see the point of this...

Comment: Try `_ = [print("Set{} Value={}".format(i,j)) for i,j in zip(Set,Value)]` after doing what Bakuriu mentioned.

Comment: Do *not* use a list comprehension for the side effects. Just use a regular loop. You are building a list object only to discard it again, this is hugely wasteful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the trick in one line:

```
Set = [1,2,3,4,5]
Value = [11,12,14,15,16]

print("\n".join([('Set{} Value={}'.format(i,j)) for i,j in zip(Set,Value)]))
```

Output:

```
Set1 Value=11
Set2 Value=12
Set3 Value=14
Set4 Value=15
Set5 Value=16
```

Comment: Or use `print(*('Set{} Value={}'.format(i,j) for i,j in zip(Set,Value)), sep='\n')` in Python 3 or with `from __future__ import print_function`. Then `print()` converts to strings for you too, which is an added advantage when producing objects that are not strings already.